# CVXPY: Equality Norm Constraints

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am confused with my constraints. I have a matrix variable with size [8,2] and two norm constraints `cp.norm(V[:,0])**2==5` and `cp.norm(V[:,1])**2==5`. But there is a error said that :

> DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
> The following constraints are not DCP:
> Pnorm(var5258[0:8, 0], 2) == 5.0 , because the following subexpressions are not:
> |-- Pnorm(var5258[0:8, 0], 2) == 5.0
> power(Pnorm(var5258[0:8, 1], 2), 2.0) == 5.0 , because the following subexpressions are not:
> |-- power(Pnorm(var5258[0:8, 1], 2), 2.0) == 5.0

I do not know why and could someone helps me?
Thanks a lot!

Pei

I read the DCP rules about equality but do not know where I did not follow the rules.

Comment: Norm can only be upper bounded. ``cp.norm()<=5`` is convex, but ``cp.norm()==5`` is not. This follows from the documentation about curvature of various operators. Or, if you want, the disk is a convex set but the circle in its boundary is not.